# How to (brute-)force-kill selected background apps?

Tags: automation, task-management, background-process

I need an **automatic brute-force method** for unrooted Android devices to kill selected apps that keep restarting in the background, i.e. an appropriate "automatic task killer". Ideally, such method entails a kill command running inside an indefinite loop. Two illustrative examples:

1. In Windows, you can run the following batch script from the command prompt:

> ```
> :start
> taskkill /f /im "process_name"
> goto start
> ```

2. In Linux, you can run the following bash script from the terminal:

> ```
> while true
> do
>     pkill -f process_name
> done
> ```

What I need is an equivalent for Android, but unfortunately, I do not have any experience with programming Android applications yet.

I have tested several "task killer" apps such as [SuperFreezZ](https://f-droid.org/packages/superfreeze.tool.android/), but you can only terminate processes manually with those. If Android decides to restart a terminated or frozen process against your will, the new instance is not automatically terminated, rendering all these apps useless.

Are there any apps out there that can get the job done? If not, is there a simple way to implement a background script for Android and have it run permanently?

IMPORTANT NOTE: I do not - I repeat - **I do not** care about CPU/memory/battery usage or any overhead caused by the task-killing app. The sole purpose is to kill selected background apps as soon as they get (re)started, be it by Android or user action. A small app or script that just keeps sending appropriate kill commands every few milliseconds would do the job (hence "brute force"). The assumption here is that one cannot prevent Android from restarting apps in the background without rooting the device, but one can keep force-closing them the moment they are launched.

For better motivation, one (out of several) use cases for me is terminating Samsung's infamous [Game Optimizing Service (GOS)](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/03/samsung-says-app-throttling-is-for-heat-management-will-let-users-disable-it/), which cannot be uninstalled even via `adb` as it gets immediately reinstalled (reminiscent to malware). When terminated by the user, it gets restarted after several minutes. An appropriate task killing app would automate the termination process for the user and ensure that GOS is running only for a miniscule fraction of system run time. There are several more reasons for me to desire such solution, which I do not want to get into here as it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151904/discussion-between-morrison-chang-and-srhslvmn).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using an automation app, plus using adb over wireless as stated by @Andrew T. and @Morrison Chang respectively.

**A. Enable Wireless debugging**

1. Make sure that Developer options is enabled.
2. In the Developer options, enable Wireless debugging.

**B. Using Automate**

You can use [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) or other apps such [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), Tasker, etc.

1. Open Automate, go to Settings.
2. Under "Privileged & Superuser" section, select "Privileged service start method", then select "Android Debug Bridge (ADB)".
3. A notification will appear. Press `Show`. The Developer options will open. Go to Wireless debugging and select `Pair device with pairing code`.
4. Another notification will appear. Enter the code shown. Automate will be wirelessly paired using adb.
5. Go back to Automate and create the flow shown on the picture below.
6. Press `+`, go to Date & Time, select `Delay`.
7. Press the Delay block, press Duration and enter the duration the block must wait. Press `Save`.
8. Press `+`, go to Apps, select `Apps in foreground?`.
9. Set it `Proceed` to `Immediately`. Seclect the package (this is the app you want to stop). Press `Save`.
10. Link the Delay and `Apps in foreground?` blocks.
11. Press `+`, go to Apps, select `App kill`. Select the package you want to stop. Press `Save`
12. Link `Apps in foreground?`'s `No` path to the `In` path of the `App kill` block.
13. Link `Apps in foreground?`'s `OK` path to the `In` path of the `Delay` block.
14. Optional, to select all blocks, press on `Copy` icon, then `Paste` icon. Change the package to stop on the new blocks.
15. Press `Back` button/gesture. Press `Start`
16. Give the necessary permissions if requested.
17. Press `Start`, select the starting points, then `Start`. Or press `Start All`.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your suggestion. I've installed the latest version of Automate, but I don't quite understand your solution yet. See also my questions in the comments below he question: Why do you need an `adb` connection? Is it just to set up the this flow chart/code or do you need a permanent debugging connection for your solution to work (= would render it impractical for mobile devices)? Also: Why not use the privileged service start method ***Manually (Execute "sh /sdcard/Android/data/com.llamalab.automate/cache/start.sh")*** instead?

Comment: Okay, first problem with your solution: I've followed all your steps, set up one Automate flow and tried to start it. But when trying to grant the permission *"access screen content and observe your actions"* and confirming the subsequent popup prompts, nothing happens (i.e. the permission is not granted). What is the issue here?

Comment: ...to be more precise: I keep cycling/bouncing back and forth between the two confirmation prompts *"Automate requires the following privilege..."* (confirm by tapping *"Grant"*) and *"Automate uses the Accessibility API to..."* (confirm by tapping *"Ok"*).

Comment: Update: Okay, the problem with granting *"access screen content and observe your actions"* permissions is solved, I had the package `com.samsung.accessibility` uninstalled, which is required by Automate. But upon running the suggested flow, the following errors are displayed in the log:

Comment: *Flow beginning >> Delay >> App in foreground? >> App kill >> Failed to start privileged service >> java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Please execute: sh /sdcard/Android/data/com.llamalab.automate/cache/start.sh >> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Service startup timeout >> Stopped by failure*

Comment: Automate has full access to external storage. In addition, I granted permission to execute shell commands. What is the problem?

Comment: It usually happens when Wireless ADB is switched off by the phone by the phone when not in use after certain amount of time. I don't know how long. Check if Wireless Adb is still on?

Comment: Hi, I'm not using wireless `adb`. Why is this required? There is also an option that uses a local bash script *"/sdcard​/Android​/data​/com.llamalab.automate​/cache​/start.sh"*, what about that? Furthermore, is it really necessary to use `adb` from a remote device or does Android come with something like a built-in/local version of it (anything that can automatically execute shell commands locally)? Having to hook up a **mobile** device to a PC every time seems incredibly impractical and contradicts the use of Android to begin with.

Comment: So, you didn't follow the method mentioned on the answer and yet complaining about it.

Comment: Nope! The question explicitly says *"What I need is an **equivalent for Android**, but unfortunately, I do not have any experience with programming **Android applications** yet."* `adb` is *not* a locally running Android app, but a debugging tool intended to be used from a Windows or Linux PC, which one usually doesn't carry around (or do you?). Importantly: I *did* install Automate, grant all necessary permissions, create a flow, and try to run it, i.e. follow through with all instructed steps faithfully, up until the point where I'm requested to have a PC on me at all times - a non-solution.

Comment: ...by the way, all this was already brought up in my *very first comment* right below your suggested answer. Which you completely ignored! You should at least be able to explain your solution after making the inquirer invest hours of lifetime into testing it out. I am happy to throw out another bounty for you, but I need a working solution first: I.e. a 100% **local solution** (maybe *one* initial connection to an external device) for **unrooted Android 9+** devices.